# Importing references but without printing the file where the references are

Tags: cross-referencing

I maintain a document that consists of several versions. Each version is another logical unity, the content is not the same. However, it can be the case that I would like to refer to a label from a previous version to current version. I tried the xr package but it doesn't quite work.

I include a mwe. Below is the main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,hyphens]{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}        

%\subfile{PartI} %This part is commented because it shouldn't be printed but its references should be loaded
\subfile{PartII}

\end{document}
```

This is file "PartI.tex" from a previous version of the document that shouldn't be printed but its references should be loaded.

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{tref1}
This is a file that should not be printed. 
The references have to be   imported though to another file. 

\section{Section}
\label{tref2}
This is a file that should not be printed. 
The references have to be imported though to another file.  

\end{document}
```

And below is file "PartII" that should be printed and I need to refer to labels in PartI.

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\externaldocument[P1-]{PartI.tex}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\label{sec1}
This text should be printed and references from file PartI.tex should be imported. 
References are \ref{P1-tref1} and \ref{P1-tref2}.


\end{document}
```

Apparently referecing does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: "not work" isn't very descriptive, what error did you get? did you run latex on PartI.tex (and not delete the aux file) before processing PartII.tex ?

Comment: If you are using subfiles then you don't want xr at all, you just treat it all as one document.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a warning that PartI.tex.aux did not exist. So, I moved the

> \externaldocument[P1-]{PartI.tex}

to the preamble of the main document and removed the ".tex" from the declaration of PartI like

> \externaldocument[P1-]{PartI}

Then, I compiled PartI, PartII, and the main file separately and result is as required.

We can consider this closed. Thanks.